# How to alter database without deleting it SQLAlchamey

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Currently I am using an SQLite database with SQLAlchamey and Flask in a web application I am working on.  Every time I make a change to the database schema like adding a column I have to delete the old database and make the new one like this.

```
    confirm = input('Are you sure you want to reset the database(y/n): ')
    if not confirm or confirm[0].lower() != 'y':
        print('Canceled')
        exit(0)
    print('Dropping Old DB')
    db.drop_all()
    print('Creating new DB')
    db.create_all()
    print('Adding default admin')
    u = User('admin', 'password', 'Application', 'Admin', User.ADMIN, 'admin@t2t.com', None)
    db.session.add(u)
    db.session.commit()
    print('Finished!')
```

While this works in the development phase it would be pretty bad if I had to dump a years worth of data once we put this into production.  How can I make SQLAlcahmey just ALTER the table?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Alchemy and generating ALTER TABLE statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106922/sql-alchemy-and-generating-alter-table-statements)

Answer (score 3):

Every time you make a change to your SQLAlchemy models, you need to change the schema with a migration. SQLAlchemy doesn't have migrations built in, but there are several other libraries that can help you do it. The most popular is probably [Alembic](https://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). If you're using Flask, there are some other things like [Flash-Migrate](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-Migrate) that wrap Alembic to make it a little easier (provides lots of commands that integrate with Flask-Script). Generally, Alembic can *mostly* detect the changes you make, but you might have to go in and edit the migration scripts by hand for certain things.

The [Flask-Migrate docs](http://flask-migrate.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) are a good place to start.